# How to table date according to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Given table like:

```
    +---------+------+--------+-----------+--------------+
    | Empcode | name | desig  | joinmonth | releivemonth |
    +---------+------+--------+-----------+--------------+
    |      1. | A1.  |    D1. | Jan-18.   |    null      |
    |      2. | A2.  |    D2. | Jan-18.   |    May-18    |
    |      3. | A3.  |    D3. | Jan-18.   |    null      |
    +---------+------+--------+-----------+--------------+
```

I want to show table like:

```
    +---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |    Remarks    | jan-18 | feb-18 | mar-18 | apr-18 | may-18 |
    +---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
    | Joinmonth     |      3 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
    | Releivedmonth |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      1 |
    +---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: what is your dbms ?

Comment: Look at `PIVOT` or `UNPIVOT`.

Comment: Mssql Database Engine

Comment: I tried in pivot but im not getting it

Comment: It is ESSENTIAL you tell which database, because each db vendor uses different syntax (nb: version is also important).

Comment: Microsoft sql database 2012

Comment: Could you please provide me answer very soon

Comment: *"I tried in pivot but im not getting it"* [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) starts by explaining that you need to say what you have tried in the question. If you [edit] the question to include what you have tried and why it's not working, people could help you fix it. (It also explains why it's important to include all the relevant tags - you can edit the question to change the tags.)

Comment: Select empname as remarks,(1-1-18),(1-2-18),(1-3-18),(1-4-18),(1-5-18) From (select empname,joimonth,releivedmonth from emply) as s Pivot (count(releivedmonth) for joinmonth in ((1-1-18),(1-2-18),(1-3-18),(1-4-18),(1-5-18)) piv

Comment: please edit and update your question with the query that you have tried

Answer (score 1):

You need to unpivot and then re-pivot:

```
select remarks,
       sum(case when mon = 'jan-18' then 1 else 0 end) as jan_18,
       sum(case when mon = 'feb-18' then 1 else 0 end) as feb_18,
       sum(case when mon = 'mar-18' then 1 else 0 end) as mar_18,
       sum(case when mon = 'apr-18' then 1 else 0 end) as apr_18,
       sum(case when mon = 'may-18' then 1 else 0 end) as may_18
from t cross apply
     (values ('Joinmonth', t.Joinmonth), ('Receivedmonth', Receivedmonth)
     ) v(remarks, mon)
group by remarks
```

Comment: lol "*You need to unpivot and then re-pivot:*" What you say is true, but you have done both without using either unpivot or pivot features.

Comment: @Used_By_Already . . . I find those "features" to be redundant and weak as features.  Lateral joins and conditional aggregation are much more flexible.

Comment: @Gordon_Linoff I agree absolutely, particularly pivot.

Answer (score 0):

> This is an extended comment rather than answer, please accept that I
>   needed formatting controls before down-voting this.

You appear to have added a query into a comment, although the syntax wasn't fully correct. You have often used standard parentheses `()` instead of brackets `[]` and there was a closing parenthesis missing to terminate the `IN()`. I believe your query should look like this:

```
SELECT
    empname AS remarks
  , [1-1-18]
  , [1-2-18]
  , [1-3-18]
  , [1-4-18]
  , [1-5-18]
FROM (
    SELECT
        empname
      , joimonth
      , releivedmonth
    FROM emply
) AS s
PIVOT (
    COUNT(releivedmonth) 
    FOR joinmonth IN ([1-1-18], [1-2-18], [1-3-18], [1-4-18], [1-5-18])
) piv
```

You should not attempt to add queries to comments, instead just edit the question.

In this query you refer to values that look like **1-1-18** but in the sample of data there is nothing that looks like that at all. **What data type is the column [joinmonth]  and [releivedmonth]?**

With data that is text in those columns you have substantial problem. If for example these are all different: `Jan-18.`,`Jan 18`,`Jan-18` so they would not align as you need them to. Variations in data like this will make this impossible.

```
CREATE TABLE emply(
   Empcode      NUMERIC(9,0)
  ,empname         VARCHAR(6)
  ,desig        VARCHAR(8)
  ,joinmonth    varchar(30)
  ,releivemonth varchar(30)
);
INSERT INTO emply(Empcode,empname,desig,joinmonth,releivemonth) VALUES (1.,'A1.','D1.','Jan-18.',NULL);
INSERT INTO emply(Empcode,empname,desig,joinmonth,releivemonth) VALUES (2.,'A2.','D2.','Jan-18.','May 18');
INSERT INTO emply(Empcode,empname,desig,joinmonth,releivemonth) VALUES (3.,'A3.','D3.','Jan-18.',NULL);

SELECT
    empname AS remarks
  , [Jan-18.]
  , [Feb-18.]
  , [Mar-18.]
  , [Apr-18.]
  , [May-18.]
FROM (
    SELECT
        empname
      , joinmonth
      , releivemonth
    FROM emply
) AS s
PIVOT (
    COUNT(releivemonth) 
    FOR joinmonth IN ([Jan-18.], [Feb-18.], [Mar-18.], [Apr-18.], [May-18.])
) piv
```

The output from this however is:

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    | remarks | Jan-18. | Feb-18. | Mar-18. | Apr-18. | May-18. |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 | A1.     |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |
|  2 | A2.     |       1 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |
|  3 | A3.     |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

There is only one non-null value of `COUNT(releivemonth)`

Comment: Both columns are varchar

Comment: that is a great pity.... if they were date or datetime then you could control the format of output, but with text you have a nightmare.